# Spring Contracts with third-party or non-Java applications

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

We are planning to use Spring Cloud Contracts to test our service endpoints.
As per the typical workflow, we will create contracts and generate stubs on the provider side, which will be used to create the consumer stub tests and provider verification tests.

My question is, can we use these same stubs to test providers that are third party services, either on prem or off? Also, can we use these stubs to test Node and Python based service providers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Please read my blog post https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/13/spring-cloud-contract-in-a-polyglot-world where i describe how to do it with nodejs. In general you can use a docker image in case where the non jvm project is a consumer or a producer. We also describe how to do it in the documentation.

Update:

It seems i have misunderstood the question. If it's related to the third party projects / apis you don't own then i can suggest the following approach. You create a test that goes to the external api via a proxy, you record the stubs and publish them as a jar (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/the-legacy-app/tree/master/stubs_with_proxy). Then the stub runner on a consumer side can fetch them. Here you can see my presentation about this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyHG-VOzPZg and the slides https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Je_IZ-xjLnOHf5YgH0r4ihlqhIrob6fC0NBT95xDHoo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this really answer the question? He asked for spring contracts for 3rd party services, which he does not own. Therefore creating the contracts on the producer side is not an option. We have the same use case currently, where we want to create stubs (like we would with wiremock) and use them for 3rd party soap services we are calling and not owning (and we cannot create consumer contracts in their repo either). Is it still good to use cloud contracts for that or does it not make sense at all (since the producer side is not tested through these contracts). Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot! so straight wiremock recording in tests rather than chosing the cloud contracts (since no consumer contracts can be written for 3rd parties) is right?

Comment: Precisely. But you can package the stubs in such a way that the consumers of this application can automatically fetch the stubs

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak It looks like the solution you linked to is storing the mocks. I want to do a consumer-driven approach, but do not (yet) have buy-in from the producer team. How can I just make a base test class that (instead of using rest assured or mock mvc) calls the producer dev/qa.

Comment: You can use the EXPLICIT mode and set RestAssured host and port to point towards the given environment